# Redis::CannotConnectError in sidekiq rspec test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rspec, sidekiq

I have written sidekiq test cases for retries block and its been there for almost a year now, but suddenly it started throwing redis error, not sure what is wrong, could someone please help me here.

Test cases:
worker_spec.rb

```
context "retries exhaust" do
      it "should retry" do
        msg = {"retry"=>1, "queue"=>"default", "args" => ""}
        LeadWorker.within_sidekiq_retries_exhausted_block(msg) {
          expect(Sidekiq.logger).to receive(:warn).at_least(:once)
        }
      end
    end
```

worker.rb

```
sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
    Sidekiq.logger.warn "Failed #{msg['class']} with #{msg['args']}: #{msg['error_message']}"
    #Recording to NewRelic
    failed_jobs = Sidekiq::Stats.new.failed
    ::NewRelic::Agent.record_metric('Custom/Sidekiq/FailedQueue', failed_jobs)
  end
```

In local test cases are running properly, but when i push changes in Jenkins its failing, error is below

```
LeadWorker perform retries exhaust should retry
     Failure/Error: failed_jobs = Sidekiq::Stats.new.failed

     Redis::CannotConnectError:
       getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
.
.
.
```

Its throwing error for **Sidekiq::Stats.new.failed**, but not sure why suddenly my code is not working.

Comment: Seems like a missing redis server in your test environment.

Comment: Yea, but not getting why does Sidekiq::Stats calls live redis in test now

Comment: I can't see your code telling it not to use a live redis, perhaps it always was and that's just been removed from your Jenkins env recently. Try stopping your local redis server and see if that impacts your local test runs.

Comment: Yea i tried this, but local test runs fine without local redis server running.